# JAVA Nextcloud API throws UnknownHostException when using https

Tags: java, nextcloud

I tried to implement the nextcloud api in Java.
I used this API (https://github.com/a-schild/nextcloud-java-api) and it's self explained but i have serious Problems in Connecting to the Server.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    String serverName = "https://<domain>/nextcloud/";
    boolean useHTTPS = true; 
    int port = 443;
    String userName = "test";
    String password = "test";

NextcloudConnector nxt = new NextcloudConnector(serverName, useHTTPS, port, userName, password);
nxt.deleteUser("test2");



    }
    }
```

I'm always getting this Exception : `"Exception in thread "main" org.aarboard.nextcloud.api.exception.NextcloudApiException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: https: unknown error"`

Answer (score 3):

Try without protocol in the serverName:

```
String serverName = "<domain>/nextcloud/";
```